# How to deserialize multiple objects in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, xamarin.forms, json.net, json-deserialization

I have two different class using that I am sending json response through API to another application, in short I am getting following json response :

```
{  
   "lmob_Forms":[  
      {  
         "Fields":"Certificate Name",
         "Validation":"R",
         "TabIndex":"1",
         "FieldType":"DropdownList",
         "DateFormate":"",
         "Details":null
      },
   ],
   "drop_Salutation":[  
      {  
         "id":1,
         "idvalue":"Kumari"
      },
      {  
         "id":2,
         "idvalue":"Mrs"
      },
      {  
         "id":3,
         "idvalue":"Ms"
      }
   ]
}
```

I have searched regarding the same but not able to solve this problem, Need help, Thanks In Advance :)

Comment: You can use a tool like https://app.quicktype.io/#l=cs&r=json2csharp to generate the desired class structure and use that when deserializing the JSON.

Comment: Thanks for the response but its giving error, let me share how I am doing deserialize response :
      var objResponse1 =JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(content);

Comment: Well your JSON had an extra comma in the first array. once you remove that you should be good to go

Comment: Also use just the root object. not `List<RootObject>`, ie `var objResponse1 =JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(content);`

Comment: "Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type System.Collections.Generic.List`1[New_Dynamic_APP.RootObject]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly....

Comment: Take a look at the provided answers below.

Comment: oho sorry! by mistake I posted that comma, the original response is correct, it doesn't have extra comma,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/)

```
public class LmobForm
{
    public string Fields { get; set; }
    public string Validation { get; set; }
    public string TabIndex { get; set; }
    public string FieldType { get; set; }
    public string DateFormate { get; set; }
    public object Details { get; set; }
}

public class DropSalutation
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string idvalue { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<LmobForm> lmob_Forms { get; set; }
    public List<DropSalutation> drop_Salutation { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all create a model of your json object.

```
public class LmobForm
{
  public string Fields { get; set; }
  public string Validation { get; set; }
  public string TabIndex { get; set; }
  public string FieldType { get; set; }
  public string DateFormate { get; set; }
  public object Details { get; set; }
}

public class DropSalutation
{
  public int id { get; set; }
  public string idvalue { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
  public List<LmobForm> lmob_Forms { get; set; }
  public List<DropSalutation> drop_Salutation { get; set; }
}
```

Now, simply use Newtonsoft.Json to deserialize your JSON object as:

```
var myObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonString);
```